# How to output deprecation warnings for Kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, groovy, deprecated, lint, android-lint

I am using the following configuration snippet in my Java/Kotlin Android project in the *app/build.gradle* file:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

It generates a verbose output of Lint warnings in *.java* files when the project is compiled.
I would like to achieve the same for *.kt* files. I found out that Kotlin has [compiler options](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options):

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"]
        }
    }
}
```

However the compiler flags are not supported:

> w: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xlint:unchecked
>   w: Flag is not supported by this version of the compiler: -Xlint:deprecation

How can I output deprecation warnings for Kotlin code?

Answer (score 5):

The java compiler and kotlin compiler have completely different options. The `-Xlint` option does not exist for kotlinc. You can run `kotlinc -X` to show all the `-X` options.

The `-Xjavac-arguments` argument allows you to pass javac arguments through kotlinc.  For example:

```sh
kotlinc -Xjavac-arguments='-Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation' ...
```

In your gradle file, you can build an array of one argument:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = [
                "-Xjavac-arguments='-Xlint:unchecked -Xlint:deprecation'"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Other syntaxes may also work.

Aside: do the default warnings not include these? You could check by adding this snippet to ensure you're not suppressing warnings:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        suppressWarnings = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work: `freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjavac-arguments=['-Xlint:unchecked', '-Xlint:deprecation']"]`