# Suppress all deprecation issues in Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

In my project, all Kotlin warnings are treated as errors. For that I use the following configuration:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }
}
```

However, I want to ignore deprecation errors, the same way I'm already doing in Java with `-Xlint:all,-deprecation`

However, I can't find any documentation explaining how to do so.

I've tried using the following configuration but with no success:

```
freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjavac-arguments=['-Xlint:all,-deprecation']"]
```

This was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57212180/3410697) but it doesn't seem to work and deprecation warnings are still considered errors

Is there any option I can use to disable deprecation issues this?

Thanks

Comment: I asked this here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488930/how-to-suppress-specific-kotlinc-javac-compiler-warnings.